# Python sqlalchemy mapping tables without primary key

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a 3rd party database which I try to map with sqlalchemy and python. The table in the database does not use a primary key. And I like to avoid table definitions by myself because the table has a lot of columns. So I wrote the following code

Found the below mapper args in the documentation of sqlalchemy.

```
class MyTable(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'MyTable'
  __mapper_args__ = {'primary_key':[some_table_with_no_pk.c.uid, some_table_with_no_pk.c.bar]
.....
}
```

But to me its unclear how to add the correct naming, something like

```
{'primary_key':['MyTable', 'MyColumnInTable'] }
or
{'primary_key':'[MyTable, MyColumnInTable]' }
```

does not work. How do I map this? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4):

Found the correct syntax:

```
class Channel(Base):

   __tablename__ = 'MyTable'
   __table__ = Table(__tablename__, Base.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=Engine)   
   __mapper_args__ = {'primary_key': [__table__.c.MyColumnInTable]} 
... 
}
```

This worked for me.

Another solution would be:
Overriding Reflected Columns (found also in sqlalchemy doku)

```
Column('MyColumnInTable', Integer, primary_key=True),   # override reflected 'id' to have primary key
```

Thanks

Comment: the `__mapper_args__` solution worked for me after trying to figure out how to use a sqlite database created using a `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT *` statement, which necessarily can't have a primary key and can not be added.

Answer (score 4):

As you can read [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html):

> primary_key – A list of Column objects which define the primary key to be used against this mapper’s selectable unit. This is normally simply the primary key of the local_table, but can be overridden here.

So you can do it like this:

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my-table"

    field1 = Column(String(10))
    field2 = Column(String(10))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "primary_key":[field1, field2]
    }
```